# Angular 4/5 Render2 Jasmine testing

Tags: angular, typescript, angular5

I have an interface which intent to manipulate DOM elements based on the input argument object. I am trying to write unit test first. The idea is to use Render2 available in Angular.

```
export interface ModifyDomTree {
    modify(data: SomeData) : ElementRef;
}
```

It's implementation (No idea how this will come up) but writing test's for it.

```
export class ModifyDomTreeImpl implements ModifyDomTree {
   constructor(private render: Renderer2) {
   }
   modify(data: SomeData) : ElementRef{
        return null;
   }
}
```

In the test I don't want to use a mock for Renderer2 I want to use the actual Renderer2 which will be used by Angular. How do I inject or instantiate actual Angular Render2 in the test?

The spec would be

```
describe('ModifyDomTreeImpl', () => {
let data: SomeData;
let modifyDomTree: ModifyDomTree;

beforeEach(() => {
    //let render: Renderer2 = mock(Renderer2); ?? How Do I inject the real Angular thing here
    modifyDomTree = new ModifyDomTreeImpl(render);
});

it('should convert a data into a text node', () => {
   data = mock(SomeData);
   when(data.value).thenReturn('Groot!!');
   const result: ElementRef = modifyDomTree.convert(data);
   expect(result).toBeDefined();
   expect(result).not.toBeNull();
   expect(result.nativeElement).toBeDefined();
   expect(result.nativeElement).toBeDefined();
   expect(result.nativeElement.childNodes).toBeDefined();
   expect(result.nativeElement.childNodes.length).toEqual(1);
   expect(result.nativeElement.childNodes.length[0]).toEqual('text');
   expect(result.nativeElement.childNodes.length[0].data).toEqual('Groot!!');
  });
});
```

Comment: The most straightforward way is to make it TestBed test. But why exactly do you need 'real Angular thing' here? `expect(result.nativeElement)`, etc - this already was tested by the framework itself. That's why we use frameworks. Because we can rely on them and save time. You just need to check that Renderer2 is instantiated and its methods are called with correct args.

Comment: The thing is I am playing with contenteditable divs and the business logic decides what to be rendered. I have a directive which make the contenteditable div. A component to get data from backend service. And this particular service modifies the data from backend and put its back in the div.

Comment: The scenario looks too complex for a unit test. And in integration tests you definitely need to use TestBed instead of instantiating classes manually.

Comment: But how do I inject the real Render2 in TestBed? TestBed.configureTestingModule({
            providers: [ModifyDomTreeImpl, Renderer2]
        }); is not helping. render is just an empty object {}. Which module will have this Render2?

Comment: Because it's compiler dependency and available only in component injectors. You need to create dummy component for that and inject ModifyDomTreeImpl there. That's why testing with a stub is much cleaner.

Comment: Ohh.. I think I should go back to stub for now. And have a separate integration test if its required.

Comment: Yes, usually line-by-line unit test + broad integration/e2e test provide full coverage. Most times I'll end up with detailed unit tests alone, while e2e is ok for making sure that there are no injection or other human errors.

Answer (score 1):

This should be working with Angular 6+

In your component.spec.ts use the providers to inject the renderer.
You can then retrieve and spy on it to confirm the tests.

```
let renderer2: Renderer2;
...
beforeEach(async( () => {
   TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      ...
      providers: [Renderer2] // This is the angular renderer
   }).compileComponents();
}));

beforeEach(() => {
   fixture = TestBed.createComponent(YourComponent);
   // grab the renderer
   renderer2 = fixture.componentRef.injector.get<Renderer2>(Renderer2 as Type<Renderer2>);
   // and spy on it
   spyOn(renderer2, 'addClass').and.callThrough();
   // or replace
   spyOn(renderer2, 'addClass').and.callFake(..);
   // etc
});

it('should call renderer', () => {
    expect(renderer2.addClass).toHaveBeenCalledWith(jasmine.any(Object), 'css-class');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

manipulating directly DOM elements with angular sounds to be a very bad idea.
I would first try to understand what I really want to achieve , and if there is a better way to achieve it than modifying dynamically dom. The basics of angular is to avoid DOM manipulation directly.`

I understand that may be not easy to understand ... so, you have to think at components  in implementation. in this case , you have some case and some components fitting these cases (or one with some options) . all the options are available in div / css. BUT only enabled /visible if needed (ngIf condition in templates) . Think like you had all the options already implemented and available , only customising. This does not forbid in this case to implement DOM manipulation (by angular) only for creation of the different kinds of components at page creation / or service update:

example:

```
import { Component, OnInit , ComponentFactoryResolver, ViewContainerRef, ViewChild} from '@angular/core';

import { NicolabelComponent } from './nicolabel/nicolabel.component';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-nicoview',
  templateUrl: '
  <button (click)="addNicoLabel()">Add </button>
  <div #mydiv style="width:100px;height:200px">;
  </div>
',
  styles: []
})
export class NicoviewComponent implements OnInit {
  @ViewChild('mydiv', {read: ViewContainerRef}) mydiv;

  labels: NicolabelComponent[] = [];

  ngOnInit() {

  }
 // `ViewContainerRef` from the component itself
  constructor(private viewContainerRef:ViewContainerRef, private componentFactoryResolver: ComponentFactoryResolver) {}

labelClicked(label)
{
console.log("click : ");
console.log(label.text);
}

  addNicoLabel()
  {
  console.log("clicked");
  // to be created dynamicalaly this component must be declared in app.module.ts as an entryComponents
  let factory = this.componentFactoryResolver.resolveComponentFactory(NicolabelComponent);
  let created_component = this.mydiv.createComponent(factory);
//  this.labels.push(created_component );

  }
}
```

Comment: I am trying to separate things from framework. I have a usecase where i need to deal with contenteditable div. think a custom editor. The dom manipulation service will need to create different elements or add css etc based on certain business logic. So this particular service takes the data outputs a dom tree. To make sure things work together especially with Rendere2 as its still in experimental state I want to kind of make sure test covers the dome creation/ modification and outputs the correct dom tree.